# Как исправить ошибку 400 Python requests.POST

Tags: python, requests

Всем привет!
мне нужно залогиниться и получить токен с сайта

в curl делаю запрос вида:
curl -X POST   https://v2.name.ru/api/   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   -H 'Authorization: Basic 1c1C1ccc111CCCcc1c1c' -d data=%3D%7B%22email%22%3A%22myemail%40domain.ru%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22mypassword%22%7D

и он работает, в ответ получаю json со всеми данными

но токен мне нужно получить в Python
я пробую следующее:

```
import requests

url = 'https://v2.name.ru/api/'

data={
    'email':'myemail@domain.ru',
    'password':'mypassword'
     }
headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic 1c1C1ccc111CCCcc1c1c',
  
}
    
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
response
```

получаю ответ 400 - неверный email (при этом копипаст с терминала, где запрос отрабатывается)

Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {'data': '={"email":"myemail@domain.ru","password":"mypassword"}',}
```

Comment: благодарю, но это не помогло, ошибка такая же( {'error': {'error_code': 400, 'error_msg': 'Неверно указан email'}}

Comment: по https://curlconverter.com/ вставте свой curl

Comment: воoот таааакое спасибо!

Comment: Ну как я понял,  сработало?

Comment: да, полезная ссылка, только что это? по типу словаря? где, что нужно было почитать, чтобы самостоятельно дойти до ответа...

Comment: Попробуй закосить под браузер